# Do not select rows when one of the rows satisfies the condition

Tags: sql

Can someone explain how to do following thing?
I have a table Person and Houses. 
Person:

```
    | Person id | Person Name |
    | 1         | One         |
    | 2         | Two         |
```

Houses:

```
    | House id | Person Id | House type |
    | 1        | 1         | Small      |
    | 2        | 1         | Big        |
    | 3        | 1         | Undefined  |
    | 4        | 2         | Big        |
    | 5        | 2         | Undefined  |
```

I have a following situation:
I need to select Person who has a house with type "Big" and not select this person if he has house with type "small", select person if he has 2 houses with type "big" and "Undefined", but not select house id of house with type "Undefined".

So the result should be (just this one row)

```
| Person id | House id |
| 2         | 4        |
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: You're leaving out many combinations, for example what happens if he has big/big, big/big/undefined, ...? Maybe you could explain the desired result in another way?

Comment: Person 1 and Person 2 both have Big and Undefined Why is person 1 not listed?

Answer (score 2):

Take it step by step

> I need to select Person who has a house with type "Big"

```
SELECT DISTINCT PersonID, HouseID
FROM HOUSES
WHERE HouseType = 'Big'
```

> and not select this person if he has house with type "small",

```
SELECT DISTINCT PersonID, HouseID
FROM HOUSES
WHERE HouseType = 'Big'
  AND PersonID NOT IN (SELECT PersonID FROM HOUSES WHERE HouseType = 'small')
```

> select person if he has 2 houses with type "big" and "Undefined"

```
(SELECT PersonID FROM HOUSES WHERE HouseType = 'big')
UNION 
(SELECT PersonID FROM HOUSES WHERE HouseType = 'undefined')
```

> but not select house id of house with type "Undefined".

```
SELECT DISTINCT PersonID, HouseID
FROM HOUSES
WHERE PersonID IN (
  (SELECT PersonID FROM HOUSES WHERE HouseType = 'big')
  UNION 
  (SELECT PersonID FROM HOUSES WHERE HouseType = 'undefined')
)
  AND HouseType != 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT PersonId, HouseId
FROM Houses
WHERE HouseType = 'Big' AND 
      PersonId IN (SELECT PersonId
                   FROM Houses
                   GROUP BY PersonId
                   HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN HouseType = 'Big' THEN 1 END) >= 1 AND
                          COUNT(CASE WHEN HouseType = 'Small' THEN 1 END) = 0 AND
                          COUNT(CASE WHEN HouseType = 'Undefined' THEN 1 END) >= 1)
```

The subquery used by the `IN` operator returns `PersonId` values related to both 'Big' and 'Undefined' house types and *not* related to 'Small' ones.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa2082/4)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select case2.Person_ID, case2.House_ID
 from (
        ( -- Removes persons with Big and Small houses
            select Person_ID, count(*) as Cnt from Houses
                where House_Type in ('Big', 'Small')
            group by Person_ID
            having count(*) = 1
        ) case1
        inner join 
        (
            select Person_ID, House_ID, House_Type from Houses 
                where House_Type in ('Big', 'Undefined')
        ) case2 on case1.Person_ID = case2.Person_ID
    ) 
where House_Type <> 'Undefined'
```